# python - what does the syntax `=>` mean in a function name?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In python what does the syntax `=>` mean in a function name? What is it called and what does it do?

For example:

```
# Constant 1-D Tensor populated with value list.
tensor = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]) => [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

Comment: This is not official Python: it is frequently used to specify what the result of an expression will be.

Comment: It's not Python syntax at all. As was said above, it's just how the author tried to tell the readers what the output of running the function would be. In my opinion, it'd be better to make it a comment: `a = function()  # => this returns None`.